# Probability exercise with accidents

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If we know that someone who drives has a 1/500 chance of getting into an accident, what is the probability of this person to get into an accident at least once in a year?

I really don't know how to solve this problem. I thought about multiplying it with 364 (the days) but it looks very wrong. Any help will be truly appreciated

Comment: $1/500$ chance a day?  Are days independent?  There are $365$ (or $366$) days in a year.  Your method is probably wrong, as it would lead to a probability above $1$ for the probability of an accident in two years. You may want to find the probability of *not* having an accident on any day.

Comment: the days are independant yes. One can have two three four accidents (not in the same day obviously but during the whole year), it doesn't truly matter. We are looking for the chance to have at least one during the whole year.

Comment: If it is each day and getting into an accident any day is independent of other days, find the probability that the person does not get into accident throughout the year and then subtract from $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The person either has an accident at least once in a year, or zero accidents that year. These two probabilities must sum to $1$.

The probability that zero accidents happen on any given day is $1 - \frac{1}{500} = \frac{499}{500}$. So to have zero accidents on *every single* day of the year, the events are all independent, which gives $(499/500)^{365}$.

So your probability is $1 - (499/500)^{365} \approx 0.52$.

Comment: Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 - 1/n)^n = 1/e$, this probability is approximately $1 - (1/e)^{365/500} \approx 1 - e^{-3/4}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't mention that how many times he drives the car and many other details . ( Like going from office and coming from office will count twice )

Let's say he goes n times office a year . Then it's probability in getting accident at least once a year
$$=1-({499 \over 500})^n$$